# Rails app on percise32 vagrant box - assets get "text file busy" error (Errno::ETXTBSY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, asset-pipeline, vagrant

Trying to boot up a Rails app inside a Vagrant box (percise32) host machine is Windows 7.
This is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box      = 'precise32'
  config.vm.box_url  = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box'
  config.vm.hostname = 'rails-dev-box'

  config.vm.synched_folder "c:\rails_text", "/home/code"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3003

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
    puppet.module_path    = 'puppet/modules'
  end
end
```

When i try to run the app (code is syncing correctly) i am getting the following error on the Rails server output:

```
Errno::ETXTBSY in Welcome#index

Showing /home/code/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #4 raised:
Text file busy - (/home/code/tmp/cache/sass/a0a09a036cf07b1cae262d60fa989a8e24765858/welcome.css.scssc20131001-1595-f6clpt, /home/code/cache/sass/a0a09a036cf07b1cae262d60fa989a8e24765858/welcome.css.scssc)
  (in /home/code/app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss)
```

Some articles suggested that moving my synced folder outside of the /vagrant root is the cure, but it seems that it is not the issue in my case since i am using /home/code

ideas welcome.

Comment: The problem may be caused by synced folder (`vboxsf`), if you have large numbers of files/directories, move to NFS or `sshfs`, avoid using vboxsf which has known issues with large number of files.

Comment: I'm with the same error, if you run this code on windows 7 will work, but inside on vagrant won't. You can create a new directory but you can't shared , than will works!

Comment: just add :nfs => true ? @TerryWang

Comment: where shoudl this :nfs => true be added?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the gem for Sass recently updated (like yesterday or today)
Go to the Gemfile and set the sass version to 3.2.10, then bundle update

gem 'sass', '3.2.10' # 3.2.11 broke the app

Answer (score 3):

Solution of user2840051 work ..
You need to uninstall sass

`gem uninstall sass`

Choose version to uninstall

Modify your Gemfile with:

`gem 'sass', '3.2.10'`

And finally run:

`bundle update sass`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, after sass was upgraded to 3.2.12. My solution was to move sass cache out of synced folder to a proper linux filesystem:

```
options[:cache_location] = "/tmp/sass-cache"
```

Comment: The above suggestion can be used via command-line:

sass --cache-location "/tmp/sass-cache"

Comment: Where are you using this option configuraiton. In which file? I'm having the same issue on a Rails app.

Comment: Where are we supposed to put this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with grunt/sass and vagrant.

Message was:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ grunt
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Errno::ETXTBSY: Text file busy @ sys_fail2 - (./.sass-cache/8147710423c1a1d0096b06b58f36e8601f62e931/main.scssc20140302-6017-1phv8qn, ./.sass-cache/8147710423c1a1d0096b06b58f36e8601f62e931/main.scssc)
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The fix is, to add **cacheLocation** option into **Gruntfile.js**, sample config below.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed', // compact
                    lineNumbers : false, // true
                    cacheLocation: '/tmp/sass-cache'
                },
            },
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As a general system-wide fix

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass -v 3.2.10
```

Comment: Would be handy if someone explained the issue. I really only use Ruby for SASS right now, so I don't know what's wrong with rolling the package back to the one I want globally.