# Can I install Compass with an old version of SASS?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

When installing Compass (on Linux command line), can I specify which old version of SASS will be installed with it?

Comment: Why do you want a specific version of Sass?

Comment: Compiling Sass with Compass stopped working after latest Sass update. (Problem quite similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124367/rails-app-on-percise32-vagrant-box-assets-get-text-file-busy-error-errnoe)

Comment: If you're using Compass 1.0, you have much of a choice, because Compass 1.0 only works with Sass 3.3+.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Koala-app on my host machine, instead of Compass on the guest.

Answer (score 5):

You can install a specific version of SASS using the following command:

`gem install sass -v 3.3.4`

Replace `3.3.4` with the preferred version.

You can find a list with all versions of SASS at **[RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions)**

Comment: Installing Compass seems to install newest version of SASS automatically, even if older version is already installed. This is what I wish to avoid