# gulp-ruby-sass producing odd output

Tags: ruby, sass, npm, gulp

I'm new to gulp and am testing gulp-ruby-sass, the output files contains no css but what looks like debug output.

Gulp task (pretty much the example on [npm page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ruby-sass)):

```
gulp.task('test', function() {

    return gulp.src('./public/scss/admin/test.scss')
        .pipe(sass({sourcemap: false, loadPath: ['../common']}))
        .pipe(rename('test-scss-gulp.css'))
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist.css +'/admin'));

});
```

I get no errors and the file "public/css/admin/test-scss-gulp.css" is produced, but it's contents are:

```
{
"version": 3,
"mappings": ";AAMA,MACA;EACI,MAAM,EAAE,KAAK;EAEb,UACA;IACI,SAAS,EAAE,IAAI",
"sources": ["../test.scss"],
"names": [],
"file": "test.css"
}
```

Any idea what's happening? My other non-scss gulp tasks work fine.

I'm on sass 3.4.6 and ruby 1.9.3p194.

Comment: What is your sass version?

Comment: It could be related to this [issue comment](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/142#issuecomment-58769039). "... the current gulp-ruby-sass was written for 3.3".

Comment: I'm getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Heikki and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687642/can-i-install-compass-with-an-old-version-of-sass) for pointing me in the right direction, it's working perfectly now.

Steps:

1. `gem uninstall sass`
   When prompted to remove executables, I said Yes.
2. I then chose a sass version from [this list](http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions) and ran `gem install sass -v 3.3.14`
3. Ran `gulp test` and checked it gave the correct output (about 3 lines of css), it did.

You may need `sudo` depending on how you're logging in.